# How to change Image created in a for loop with on_press in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have created a group of images in a for loop in kivy and those images have the attribute of 'buttonbehavior' making them clickable. I am trying to change the image at a particular index to another image when clicked but it is not working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Pass
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,Image):
     pass
class Screen1(Screen, ButtonBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    for i in range(6):
        self.btn= ImageButton(source='put_any.png', size_hint=(.3, .2),
                       pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .32})
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        If i==0:
           self.btn.bind(on_press=self.change_image)

    def change_image(self,*args) 
        self.source='put_any.png'

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

I want the image at index 0 in the for loop to change to another image when it is pressed,  but it is not working please what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer self.source it means Screen.source that wont affect anything.

Change the func like this:

```
def change_image(self, btn) 
        btn.source='put_any.png'
```

Comment: after adding your code it still doesn't change the image

Comment: it works perfectly thanks, the fault was from my code.